# Create SQLCE database programmatically

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

**[EDITED - with answer]**

Following is my code to create SQL CE database programmatically:

```
/* get the Path */
var directoryName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
var fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(directoryName, "Foo2Database.sdf");

/* check if exists */
if (File.Exists(fileName))
    File.Delete(fileName);

string connStr = @"Data Source = " + fileName;

/* create Database */
SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(connStr);
engine.CreateDatabase();

/* create table and columns */
using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connStr))
{
    using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(@"CREATE TABLE FooTable (Foo_ID int, FooData NVARCHAR(200))", conn))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the Exception is thrown by  that piece of code?

Comment: If you get such a strange error, you will get the exact code line number in your strack trace. please provide more details like complete exception message and code position.

Comment: The `Close` is not required since you are using `using`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I have worked with SQLCE 3.1 and SharpDevelop, Try this code and see if this is what you want:

```
string connStr = "Data Source = FooDatabase.sdf; Password = SomePassword";

if (File.Exists("FooDatabase.sdf")) 
    File.Delete("FooDatabase.sdf");  

SqlCeEngine engine = new SqlCeEngine(connStr); 
engine.CreateDatabase();

SqlCeConnection conn = null;


try 
{
    conn = new SqlCeConnection(connStr);
    conn.Open();

    SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE FooTable(col1 int, col2 ntext)";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch 
{

}
finally 
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

Note that the database is just a file, so you can check if the database exists by looking if the file exists, also you can delete the database by deleting the file. Hope this helps.

Comment: You should use the using-statement on SqlCeEngine, SqlCeConnection and of course SqlCeCommand.

Comment: I worked on this thing a few years back, and i wanted to close the connection like in this try catch, finally method. And sadly being self taught in C#.net, i am not too familiar with new practices used :). that said, i guess i think you guys can use this code in the proper way and think of my example as an algorithm of sorts :D

Comment: thanks. according to what you've given, I've re-written my code and edit my question with answer.