# Prepare code to programmatically create SQLite database - exporting template

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite

In Microsoft Visual Express is there a way to export the SQLite database I've created through the Express interface into a code format so I can have it generated on first install by my customers?

I'd like to take the easiest way to do this without having to manually prepare all the code structure.

I was unable to find any sort of export feature. Any advice?

This [resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196274/create-sqlce-database-programatically) will help me execute the code once I have it prepared, but I've 12 tables and some of them should come pre-populated, so being able to have the batch code will help.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just an SQLite database you could just publish the file with the rest of your program since it's a normal file without any dependencies.